# Removing node from Datastax Cluster

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise, datastax-java-driver, datastax-enterprise-graph, datastax-startup

My current cluster contain **6 SearchGraph** nodes and replication factor is 2.

```
Datacenter: SearchGraph
=======================
UN  192.168.8.1  469 MiB     1            ?       936a1ac0-6d5e-4a94-8953-d5b5a2016b92  rack1
UN  192.168.8.2  427.71 MiB  1            ?       3f41dc2a-2672-47a1-90b5-a7c2bf17fb50  rack1
UN  192.168.8.3  431.27 MiB  1            ?       29f8fe44-3431-465e-b682-5d24e37d41d7  rack2
UN  192.168.8.4  480.73 MiB  1            ?       1f7de531-ff51-4581-bdb8-d9a686f1099e  rack2
UN  192.168.8.5  498.9 MiB   1            ?       27d37833-56c8-44bd-bac0-7511b8bd74e8  rack2
UN  192.168.8.6  882.4 MiB   1            ?       0822145f-4225-4ad3-b2be-c995cc230830  rack1
```

I am planning to remove exiting 3 instance from cluster. I need only 3 instance in my cluster. Can any one specify the steps to be followed with out losing data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Official documentation [describes this in good details](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/dse-admin/datastax_enterprise/operations/opsRemoveNode.html).  Basically, all you need is to run `nodetool decommission` on corresponding node. But you need to do it one by one, not all together.